# Skype won't connect on Vivid

Tags: 15.04, skype

I'm on (an upgraded) 64bit Ubuntu 15.04 and am using Skype 4.3.0.37. It had been working fine, but today I couldn't seem to login any more. The load circle keeps going round and round. Internet connection seems fine, username/login combination is correct, yet it just won't connect. Nor does it give a "no connection" error or something similar. So not sure what is causing the delay.

I tried fully removing and reinstalling skype and its folder, but that did not do any good either.

Anyone got a solution for this problem?

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate - if you believe it isnt, edit your question saying so then flag and we'll reopen this.

Comment: @cl-netbox That seems to be the problem. On the other hand, I can seemingly log in on my phone, though none of my contacts are online. So I will just give it a day and see what happens tomorrow. Thanks for the fast reply.